# How do I pause and restart a stopwatch timer using requestAnimationFrame?

Tags: javascript, canvas, timer, requestanimationframe

I'm using the requestAnimationFrame loop for a stopwatch and some other animations. I'm using a timestamp returned from the rAF to get the time, but when I stop the loop to pause the timer, wait a few seconds, then start the loop again, the timer will display the total time.

I need to be able to pause the timer and continue from the paused time. Is there a way to reset the timestamp variable after pausing the timer?
If you need me to post some of my code let me know, or if you need me to further explain myself I will do so.

**Edit**

```
    var frames = 0,
    startTime = null,
    lastTime = null,
    fps = 1000/120,
    isRunning = false,
    pTime = 0,
    timeElapsed;

function loop(timeStamp){

        if(!startTime) startTime = timeStamp;
        var timeDiff = lastTime ? (timeStamp - lastTime) : fps,
            timeScale = timeDiff / fps,
            timeElapsed += (timeStamp - startTime)/1000,
            lastTime = timeStamp;

        if(isRunning){ 
            requestAnimationFrame(loop);
            gField.t.text = ++frames + "f / "+parseInt(timeElapsed - pTime)+"s = "+parseInt(frames/(timeElapsed-pTime)) + "fps\n"+(timeDiff).toFixed(2);
        }
        /*      
        canvas manipulation e.g.
        particle.x += acc*timeElapsed;
        */
        time.text = (timeElapsed).toFixed(2);
        canvas.redraw();
};
```

This function is triggered through a button event handler. When `isRunning` is false, the loop will stop, but obviously timeStamp will increase from before when the loop is called again.

Comment: Only use your rAF for drawing, use a separate timer for the stop watch (separate drawing and calculating)

Comment: Yes, please post your code (or at least the parts that deal with the timer)

Comment: I edited the question for you

Comment: [I think my answer here may be of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208375/js-how-to-write-a-time-limit-function-for-my-stopwatch/70222208#70222208)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was an answer before but I assume the guy deleted it afterwards, but I remembered and found a way of doing it while still using the timeStamp from rAF.

```
var startTime = null,
    isRunning = false,
    timeElapsed = 0,
    pause = false,
    pTime = 0;

function loop(timeStamp){
    if(!startTime) startTime = timeStamp;

    if(isRunning && !pause){
        timeElapsed = (timeStamp - startTime) - pTime;

        time.text = (timeElapsed/1000).toFixed(2);
        canvas.redraw();

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    }else if(isRunning && pause){
        pTime = (timeStamp - startTime) - timeElapsed;
        timeElapsed = (timeStamp - startTime) - pTime;


        time.text = (timeElapsed/1000).toFixed(2);
        canvas.redraw();

        pause = false;

        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
};
```

It works by storing the difference between `timeStamp` and the original `timeElapsed` into `pTime`. Now when you calculate the elapsed time, all you need to do is subtract `pTime` from (`timeStamp` - `startTime`).

The loop is triggered by a button. Here's some example code:

```
button.onClick({
    if(isRunning){
        isRunning = false;
        pause = true;
    }else{
        isRunning = true;
        requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };
});
```

In case anyone else wants to trigger this loop through other ways.

Comment: I'm trying to adapt some of your code but I'm not clear on the role that timeStamp plays in your code. My understanding is that the timeStamp is a return value from the previous requestAnimationFrame loop, but how do you use that in comparison to the startTime and pTime? Are those relative or established using Unix epoch?

Comment: Hi, sorry it's been nearly 5 years for me now so bear with me. The timeStamp is a DOMHighResTimeStamp (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMHighResTimeStamp) which gives a more accurate point in time when the `loop` callback is fired. startTime is the very first time in which the first callback is called as there is naturally a millisecond delay on the first call if that makes sense. Hope that helps!

Comment: @DavidA.French [I wrote here a complete example, largely inspired by this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208375/js-how-to-write-a-time-limit-function-for-my-stopwatch/70222208#70222208)

Comment: What's the difference between the meaning of `isRunning` and `pause` variables?