# JS - How to write a time limit function for my stopwatch?

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch

I am trying to create a stopwatch, but I want to be able to add a time limit to when my stopwatch stops running. Is there a way I can do that? And to also create a function that clicks stop to indicate that the time did stop.

Below is the code I have right now.

```js
let offset = 0,
  paused = true;

render();

function startStopwatch(evt) {
  if (paused) {
    paused = false;
    offset -= Date.now();
    render();
  }
}

function stopStopwatch(evt) {
  if (!paused) {
    paused = true;
    offset += Date.now();
  }
}

function resetStopwatch(evt) {
  if (paused) {
    offset = 0;
    render();
  } else {
    offset = -Date.now();
  }
}

function format(value, scale, modulo, padding) {
  value = Math.floor(value / scale) % modulo;
  return value.toString().padStart(padding, 0);
}

function render() {
  var value = paused ? offset : Date.now() + offset;

  document.querySelector('#s_ms').textContent = format(value, 1, 1000, 3);
  document.querySelector('#s_seconds').textContent = format(value, 1000, 60, 2);
  document.querySelector('#s_minutes').textContent = format(value, 60000, 60, 2);
  document.querySelector('#s_hours').textContent = format(value, 3600000, 24, 2);
  if (!paused) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just check `if (value > limit)` and stop your render cycle (and/or set it to `paused` or something)

Answer (score 0):

I was intrigued by the idea of using `requestAnimationFrame` for a stopwatch,
so I did my testing...
If you have any questions, it's open!

```js
const 
  btStart = document.querySelector('#bt-start')
, btReset = document.querySelector('#bt-reset')
, zChrono = document.querySelector('#z-chrono')
, ui      = (function( chronoZone = zChrono, timOutStrEvt = 'time_out' )
    {
    const 
      one_Sec = 1000
    , one_Min = one_Sec * 60
    , one_Hrs = one_Min * 60
    , one_Day = one_Hrs * 24
    , SMHD    = [ one_Sec, one_Min, one_Hrs, one_Day ]
    , n_Dgts  = (n,t) => (`0`.repeat(n)+t.toString(10)).slice(-n)
    , timeOut = new Event( timOutStrEvt )
      ;
    let timeLimit = 0
      ;
    return {
      setTimeLimit(...t)
        {
        if (t.length > SMHD.length)  t.length = 0
        timeLimit = t.reverse().reduce((l,v,i)=>l+(v*SMHD[i]),0)
        }
    , setTimeLimit_ms(...t)
        {
        if (t.length > (SMHD.length+1))  t.length = 0
        let ms = t.pop() || 0
        timeLimit = t.reverse().reduce((l,v,i)=>l+(v*SMHD[i]), ms)
        }
    , setChrono(tim)
        {
        let
          timOut = !!timeLimit ? (tim >= timeLimit) : false
        , t_H    = n_Dgts(2,Math.floor(tim / one_Hrs))
        , t_M    = n_Dgts(2,Math.floor((tim % one_Hrs) / one_Min))
        , t_S    = n_Dgts(2,Math.floor((tim % one_Min) / one_Sec))
          ;           
        chronoZone.textContent = `${t_H}:${t_M}:${t_S}.${n_Dgts(3,tim)}`

        if (timOut) chronoZone.dispatchEvent(timeOut)

        return timOut
        }
    }
  })()
, chrono  = (function( showChrono = ui.setChrono )
    {
    let startTime   = null
      , timeElapsed = 0
      , pausedTime  = 0
      , reqRef      = null
      , reqPause    = false
      , stoped      = false
      ;
    function reqLoop(timeStamp)
      {
      startTime ??= timeStamp  // Logical nullish assignment (??=)

      if (stoped)
        {
        cancelAnimationFrame(reqRef)
        return
        }
      if (reqPause) 
        { 
        pausedTime = (timeStamp - startTime) - timeElapsed;
        }
      else
        {
        timeElapsed = parseInt((timeStamp - startTime) - pausedTime)
        reqPause    = showChrono(timeElapsed)
        }
      requestAnimationFrame( reqLoop )
      }
    return { 
      start()      { reqRef   = requestAnimationFrame(reqLoop) }
    , pause(OnOff) { reqPause = OnOff }
    , stop()       { stoped   = true  }
    , RaZ()
        {
        startTime   = null
        timeElapsed = 0
        pausedTime  = 0
        reqRef      = null
        reqPause    = false
        stoped      = false
        }
      }
    })()
  ; // constants ending

ui.setChrono(0)  // user interface init...

// ---------------------------------------------- time Limit addition 
const sTimeLimit = document.querySelector('#sl-timeLimit')
sTimeLimit.selectedIndex = 0

sTimeLimit.onchange =_=>
  {
  switch (sTimeLimit.value )
    {
    case '0':     ui.setTimeLimit(0);        break;
    case '5':     ui.setTimeLimit(5);        break;
    case '23':    ui.setTimeLimit(23);       break;
    case '2:4':   ui.setTimeLimit(2,4);      break;
    case '1:2:3': ui.setTimeLimit(1,2,3);    break;
    case '1.456': ui.setTimeLimit_ms(1,456); break;
  } }
// ------------------------------------- time Limit addition ending

btStart.onclick =_=>
  {
  switch (btStart.textContent)
    {
    case 'start':
      chrono.RaZ()
      chrono.start()
      btStart.textContent = 'pause'
      break;
    case 'pause':
      chrono.pause(true)
      btStart.textContent = 'continue'
      break;
    case 'continue':
      chrono.pause(false)
      btStart.textContent = 'pause'
      break;
    }
  }
btReset.onclick =_=>
  {
  chrono.stop()
  ui.setChrono( 0 )
  btStart.textContent = 'start'
  btStart.disabled    = false 
  }
zChrono.addEventListener('time_out',()=>
  {
  btStart.disabled    = true 
  chrono.stop()
  alert (`Time limit elapsed >= ${sTimeLimit.selectedOptions[0].textContent.trim()}`)
  })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  }
button {
  width          : 6em;
  text-transform : capitalize;
  }
h2 {
  padding : 0 2em;
  color   : darkblue;
  }
```

```html
<button id="bt-start" >start</button>
<button id="bt-reset" >reset</button>
<select id="sl-timeLimit">
  <option value="" selected disabled> set time limit..?</option>
  <option value="0"     > no time limit               </option>
  <option value="5"     > 5 seconds                  </option>
  <option value="23"    > 23 seconds                 </option>
  <option value="2:4"   > 2 minutes & 4 seconds      </option>
  <option value="1:2:3" > 1 hour 2 minutes 3 seconds </option>
  <option value="1.456" > 1s 456 ms                 </option>
</select>
<h2 id="z-chrono">00-------</h2>
```