# Countdown Timer and Animation Not In Sequence

Tags: html, jquery, css, countdown

I am messing around with a countdown timer and noticed that the numeric time and svg circle animation are not in sequence at the end of the countdown. And, it gets worse as you add more minutes!

I tried adjusting the css animation delay and the script timing but can't seem to get it working right. Any ideas are welcomed.

Here is a link to the timer:
https://jsfiddle.net/jottin/cw3o6jvp/5/

```
  <div class="body">

    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class=" col-xs-12">
          <h1 class="text-center">Timer</h1>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-----------------range inputs--------------------------------------------->
      <div class="row sliders">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-6">
          <h4>Minutes<span id="workspan"></span></h4>
          <input type="number" min="1" max="60" id="workrange" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-----------------svg image and clock----------------------------------------------->
      <div class="row" id="svg-container">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
          <svg id="svgElem" viewbox="0 0 240 240" preserveAspectRatio="xMinyMin meet">
          <g id="group" transform="rotate(-90 120,120)">
            <circle id="backdrop" r="90" cy="120" cx="120" stroke-width="3" stroke="#444" fill="none"></circle>

            <circle id="workProgress" r="90" cy="120" cx="120" stroke-width="3" stroke="#45b1a1" fill="none"></circle>
          </g>
        </svg>

        </div>
        <div class="timeBtn">
          <button id="start">Start</button>
          <div id="timer"></div>
          <button id="reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <audio id="beep">
    <source src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/beep_short.ogg"/>
  </audio>
```

```
.body {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #222;
  color: #e7e7e7;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 1em;
}

#svg-container {
  position: relative;
}

.timeBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

#timer {
  font-size: 3em;
}

button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  color: #e7e7e7;
}

/*---------------style the range bars-----------------------*/
input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
/*---------------------FIREFOX------------------------*/
#workrange {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
/*---------------work range------------------------*/
 #workrange::-moz-range-thumb {
  background: #45b1a1;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#workrange::-moz-range-track {
  height: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #45b1a1;
}
#workrange::-moz-range-progress {
  height: 6px;
  background: #45b1a1;
}

/*-----------------------CHROME-----------------------*/
/*---------------------work range----------------------*/
#workrange::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: #45b1a1;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#workrange::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6px;
  background: #45b1a1;
}

/*----------------IE(edge only)?--------------------*/
/*----------workrange------*/
#workrange::-ms-track {
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #45b1a1;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
#workrange::-ms-fill-lower {
  background: #45b1a1;
}
#workrange::-ms-thumb {
  background: #45b1a1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*------------------svg animation----------------*/

#workProgress {
  stroke-dasharray: 570px;
  stroke-dashoffset: 570px;
}

#workProgress.ani {
  animation-name: progressAnimation;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-direction: reverse;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

@keyframes progressAnimation {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 570px;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 525px) {
  body {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var worktime = 1;
  var working = true;
  var isRunning = false;
  var interval;
  var getAudio = $('#beep').trigger('load');
  //getAudio.load();
 
  document.getElementById('workrange').disabled = false;
  
  
  var workrange = $('#workrange');
  var workspan = $('#workspan');
  var timer = $('#timer');

  //set the default values----------------------------
  timer.text((worktime<10?"0" + worktime: worktime) + ":" + "00");

  workrange.val(1);
  workspan.text(' ' + '1');

  //update range display when inputs changed---------------------
  workrange.on("input", function() {
    workspan.text(' ' + workrange.val());
  });

  //get the user inputs-----------------------------------
  
  workrange.bind('mouseup touchend', function() {
    worktime = $(this).val();
    timer.text((worktime<10?"0"+worktime:worktime) + ":" + "00");
  });


//function for countdown--------------------------
function countdown(mins, secs) {
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(mins == 0 && secs <= 0) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $('#workProgress').removeClass('ani');
      getAudio.trigger('play');
      if(working) {
        $('#workProgress').css({'animation-duration': worktime*60+ "s"}).addClass('ani');
        working = true;
      }
    }
    if(secs < 0) {
      mins--;
      secs = 59;
    }
    timer.text((mins<10?"0"+mins:mins) + ":" + (secs<10?"0"+secs:secs));
    secs--;
  },1000);
}

//---------------------start the countdown------------------------------------
$('#start').click(function() { 
  if(!isRunning) {
    countdown(worktime, 0);
    $('#workProgress').css({'animation-duration': worktime*60+ "s"}).addClass('ani');
    isRunning = true;
  }
  document.getElementById('workrange').disabled = true;
});

//-------------------------reset the countdown---------------------------------
$('#reset').click(function() {
  if(isRunning) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $('#workProgress').removeClass('ani');
    timer.text((worktime<10?"0"+worktime:worktime) + ":" + "00");
    isRunning = false;
  }
  document.getElementById('workrange').disabled = false;
});

});
```

Comment: I've checked your fiddle and tested using 4min, it ended up pretty nice. There's any specific time value that is causing the issue?

Comment: You must use the same chrono time for your circle and time display. This mean no css animation and no (and never) the use of delay value in `setInterval` [see why(Delay restrictions)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval#delay_restrictions). the better way for this synchronization is [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) ->[to get an idea of what to do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208375/js-how-to-write-a-time-limit-function-for-my-stopwatch/70222208#70222208)

Comment: I'm being picky. I don't like the fact that the timing is inconsistent between the two. I will look into using the same chrono (which was my feelings too). I need a way to visualize the countdown though and haven't found a working example similar to my case.