Understanding how requestanimationFrame works
I am trying to understand the requestAnimationFrame api but I am not able to understand how repaint occurs during the process.
I am working on a programming exercise to create a stopwatch.
function startTimer() {
  timerId = requestAnimationFrame(updateTimer);
}

function updateTimer() {
   timer.textContent = updateTime();
   timerId = requestAnimationFrame(updateTimer);
}

I understand that the requestAnimationFrame tells the browser to call the callback function updateTimer before the next browser repaint. But, I am assuming that the calculations inside the callback function updateTimer are causing the repaint in the first place.
So, I am struggling to understand how the repaint is triggered in this scenario? Does requestAnimationFrame triggers the repaint?

have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70208375/js-how-to-write-a-time-limit-function-for-my-stopwatch/70222208#70222208

My understanding is that repaint is triggered in synch with monitor refresh rate - I mean, why would you need to repaint between monitor frames.

@JaromandaX and so are rAF callbacks, not sure what's your point here.

what does "and so are rAF callbacks" even mean? they are what?

@JaromandaX "triggered in synch with monitor refresh rate" what else?

Perhaps my English is inelegant - OP was suggesting changing .textContent would trigger (immediately?) a repaint - I merely suggested that repaints are synchronised with refresh of monitor

Op is asking about rAF though


Does requestAnimationFrame triggers the repaint?

Not really no. It will force the browser to queue an update the rendering task, and, in Chrome, it will cause a Composite Layer, meaning it's not free, but it's not necessarily equivalent to a full "paint".
What will cause a new paint in your case is that you changed the textContent of your node, and, unless the node isn't in the tree, or hidden, this will force a paint after the next update the rendering.
You can think of requestAnimationFrame as a setTimeout(fn, time_before_next_paint). It only schedules your callback, and then forces a lot of minor checks, but these would anyway have happened even if using another timer method.
